# Call to a member function store() on null

Tags: laravel

I'm just wondering why this doesn't work for my Item Controller however on other controller it worked.

Controller for Item

```
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;

    $item = new Item;

    $item->store_id = $userId;
    $item->name = $request->name;
    $item->description = $request->description;
    $item->unit_price = $request->unit_price;

    $path = $request->image->store('images', 'public');
    $item->picture = $path;

    $item->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $item->is_available = 1;
    $item->is_archived = 0;

    $item->save();

    return redirect('/store/index')->with('status', 'Item successfully added!');
}
```

HTML form for creating item data

```
<form method="post" action='{{ url("item/store/$stores->id") }}' enctype="mutlipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <input placeholder="Item Name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder="Item Description" type="text" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" required autocomplete="off">
        <input placeholder="000.00" type="decimal" name="unit_price" value="{{ old('unit_price') }}" required autocomplete="off">

        <input type="file" name="picture" required>

        <label>Category</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
            <option value selected disabled>Select Category</option>
            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
</form>
```

Thank you for answering

Comment: dd($request->all()) please :)

Comment: `<form method="post" action="{{ url('item/store/'.$stores->id) }}"enctype="multipart/form-data">` try this in form method.

Comment: and dd($request->file('image')) too please :)

Comment: Hi, your file name is `picture` not `image`,  change this line `$request->image->store...` to   `$request->picture->store...`

Comment: i tried every suggestion but it still shows Call to a member function store() on string

Answer (score 0):

There are no any input file named `image` your input file name is `picture`. 
if you have a file field, and you try to check it with `$request->has(‘file’)`, it will always return `FALSE`. For files there is a specific method :

```
$path = $request->image->store('images', 'public');
$item->picture = $path;
```

Change to

```
$path = "no_image.png";

if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
  // $path = $request->picture->store('images', 'public');
  $file = $request->picture;
  $fName = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $file->move('images', $fName );
  $path = 'images/'.$fName;
}

$item->picture = $path;
```

Comment: I tried changing image to picture but still shows Call to a member function store() on string

Comment: it saves the assigned "no_image.png" instead. thank you for giving another idea, I'll try and restructure the code you gave me.

Comment: $path = $request->image->store('images', 'public');

This specific code is the one causeing error. I even tried changing the "image" to "picture" but still shows Call to a member function store() error

Comment: @IvanvielleDupaya, I changed your `store` method to `move` method, try this, it will work